# Убрать проверку путей в реестре

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetPath()
{
   try
   {
   using (var Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SteamPath64, true))
   {
     using (var Key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SteamPath32, true))
     {
     if (Key != null)
         return (string)Key.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
     else if (Key2 != null) 
         return (string)Key2.GetValue("SourceModInstallPath").ToString();
     }
   }
     return GetPath();
   }
   catch 
   { 
      return null; 
   }
}
```

Подскажите как сделать проверку без использовать `Key != null` ?

Comment: версия C#? Если 6+ то `Key?.GetValue(...)`

Comment: @rdorn, 2015 версия.

Comment: Эм... версия языка и версия студии совсем разные вещи, впрочем вряд ли вы меняли умолчания студии, поэтому будем считать что 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для C# 6.0+ можно изменить ваш код например так:

```
public static string GetPath()
{
    using (var Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SteamPath64, true))
    using (var Key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SteamPath32, true))
    {
        return Key?.GetValue("InstallPath")?.ToString() ?? Key2?.GetValue("SourceModInstallPath")?.ToString();
    }
}
```

в случае отсутствия первого ключа или его значения, будет запрошен второй. Если и он отсутствует - вернется null.

Ни какой магии тут нет, все необходимые проверки будут сделаны, их подставит компилятор.

Comment: Мне нужно ещё возвращать `string GetPath();` прописывая `return GetPath();`, он мне пишет "Обнаружен недостижимый код"

Comment: @ArteS это две разных строки... вы уверены что их должна возвращать одна и та же функция? и что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас в коде потерялся `try`

Comment: Ну а если я оберну всё это в `try/catch` то мне нужно будем возвратить какое-то сообщение если путей нет, если есть возвратить GetPath() в любом случае.

Comment: @ArteS а ничего что это будет рекурсивный вызов, к тому же без условий на остановку и закончится он переполнением стека и соответствующим исключением? ли это какой-то другой GetPath()? но в вашем коде это не видно

Comment: @rdom, хм, да Вы правы. =) Спасибо.

Comment: `public static string GetPath()` по сути `string` можно убрать?

Comment: @ArteS ни в коем случае. Это тип возвращаемого значения, а возвращаем мы либо найденную строку, либо null (допустимо для типа string)